# Lack of memory for experiment designs by ccd in R

Tags: r, sampling, experimental-design

I want to generate central-composite design in `R` for 60 factors. I use `ccd` function in `rsm` as `ccd(60)`. However, I got the error like below:

> Error in rep.int(rep.int(seq_len(nx), rep.int(rep.fac, nx)), orep) : 
>     vector is too large

I know there would be 2^60 experiments by default which would contribute to the lack of memory. I want to know if there are some properties in `ccd`" function which would reduce the number of experiment below 2000 experiments? For example considering 1/2 or 1/4 fractions of experiments.

Comment: You do realize that even with 1/4 fractions of experiments you still have more than 288,000,000,000,000,000 experiments? To reduce this to 2000 experiments, you need a 1/1,730,000,000,000,000 fraction experiment. I'd stop looking at R and rethink the question.

Comment: When the number of factors is 5 or greater, it is not necessary to run all combinations of factors. The factorial part of the design can be run in a fraction of the total number of available points. There may be either regular fractional factorials or Min Run Res V (minimum run, resolution V) designs as options (From Design Expert Software Manual).
I used this option for **44 variables** and **1086 experiments** were designed. However, the software does not support the number of variables more than 50.

Comment: Check the resolution of a 2^(60 - 49) design. I hope the aliasing will make clear to you why "the software gives a result" is not the same as "the result of the software has any practical value".

Comment: Hmmm. This is like reading that someone bought a new Maserati, and is disappointed that it's not designed to go 100,000 MPH. I suspect that you don't even want a CCD of any description, since such designs are used for estimating second-order response surfaces. I suspect you just want a screening design. There are other packages that may provide better support for those - like perhaps **FrF2**. See the *ExperimentalDesign* task view: https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/ExperimentalDesign.html

Comment: But really I should have said this the first time: Try to cut your list of factors down to begin with. You can't answer all the world's questions in one experiment, and it is foolish to even try. Pick out 10 or fewer factors that seem most promising, and hold others fixed at reasonable levels.